# Upgrading from 0.4.x to 0.5.x ASP Boilerplate and breaking change #249

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a project based on ASP.NET Boilerplate http://aspnetboilerplate.com and for reasons outside of my control I have had to upgrade the project from 0.4.x to 0.5.x. Clearly stated in the change logs (http://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Change-Logs) is the following breaking change:

**Changed base repository constructor for EntityFramework**

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/249

However for the life of me I cannot figure out how I change my existing base class to support this. My code is as follows:

```
    public class MlRepositoryCommon<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> : EfRepositoryBase<MlDbContext, TEntity, TPrimaryKey> where TEntity : class, IEntity<TPrimaryKey>
    {
        //Add common methods for repositories
    }

    public class MlRepositoryBase<TEntity> : MlRepositoryCommon<TEntity, long> where TEntity : class, IEntity<long>
    {
    }

   public class MlDbContext : AbpDbContext
    {
        public MlDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }
   }
```

and the compilation error is:

```
'Abp.EntityFramework.Repositories.EfRepositoryBase<MakersLane.Infrastructure.EntityFramework.EntityFramework.MlDbContext,TEntity,TPrimaryKey>' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
```

I would appreciate any help with this as I now have a looming deadline and no compiling solution :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your repository should take a IDbContextProvider<YourDbContext> as constructor parameter. That's all.

A sample repository:

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate-samples/blob/master/SimpleTaskSystem/SimpleTaskSystem.EntityFramework/EntityFramework/Repositories/SimpleTaskSystemRepositoryBase.cs

And a repository derived from it:

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate-samples/blob/master/SimpleTaskSystem/SimpleTaskSystem.EntityFramework/EntityFramework/Repositories/TaskRepository.cs

Comment: Thanks again Halil. For those interested there is more detail in  https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/307